# Add column in SQL with repetitve Serial number for new value in another column

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I need to have a column that can identify the sequence of a particular column (name in the given example) and it starts over from 1 for new name. Please see the below table. I DONT need count of the repetitive value, I want their occurrence to record. e.g. if coming for first time in table show 1 in front of it, if coming second time then 2 and so on.... and again show 1 for new value encountered in the column.

I am trying to achieve it in Excel VBA SQL query....

[Please see the requirement here... I need to calculate column ID as per above explanation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hSUMB.png)

[image]

Comment: Tag the DBMS (i.e. `MySQL`, `SQL Server`, etc..) that you are using.

Comment: Sorry for the insufficient data and thanks for quick response... to provide complete data............ I am trying to achieve it in Excel VBA SQL query. I am not able to use row_number().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Fromula =COUNTIF($A$2:A2,A2)  it will resolve your issue. if any query please comment.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Most of DBMS has `row_number()` function, so i would use it :

```
select t.*, row_number() over (partition by name order by ?) as seq
from table t;
```

If, the DBMS doesn't have `row_number()` function, then you can use subquery :

```
select t.*, ( select count(*)
              from table t1
              where t1.name = t.name and t1.pk <= ?
            ) as seq
from table t;
```

`?` indicate your `pk` (`primary key`) column which has unique unique value across the table that specify your column ordering.

Comment: thank yogesh... I am using it in excel vba (SQL) query... could you suggest the edit accordingly. Thanks for your response and apologies for insufficient data before.